# Assign `AllowedValues` based on another parameter

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm just learning CloudFormation and have hit something that's bugging me.  Is it possible to assign `AllowedValues` for one parameter based on the selected value of another parameter?

For example, is there a way to do something like below?  If not, can anyone recommend a different way to handle this kind of situation where the allowed values for one parameter depend on the value of another parameter?

```
Mappings:
  P2AllowedVals:
    Val1:
      Values:
        - v11
        - v12
    Val2:
      Values:
        - v21
        - v22

Parameters:
  Param1:
    AllowedValues:
    - Val1
    - Val2
    Default: Val1
    Type: String
  Param2:
    AllowedValues: !FindInMap [P2AllowedVals, !Ref "Val1", Values]
```